# .NET MAUI 7 - SwipeView inaccessible in code-behind

Tags: c#, code-behind, maui

The SwipeView is in a CollectionView, that is accessible via its x:Name attribute. But I cannot access the SwipeView via its x:Name:

```
<SwipeView x:Name="swipe">
    <SwipeView.RightItems>
        <SwipeItems >
            <SwipeItem />
        </SwipeItems>
    </SwipeView.RightItems>
    <Label Text="SomeText"/>
</SwipeView>
```

When I try to do 'swipe.IsEnabled' in the code behind, it displays "The name 'swipe' doesn't exist in the current context."

Comment: Can you show the surrounding XAML and the relevant parts of the code behind? Is the SwipeView by any chance inside a DataTemplate? In that case, you cannot access it via its name.

Comment: controls inside templates are not accessible by name.  Use data binding to interact with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as Jason suggested, you can use data binding to set the `IsEnabled` of the `SwipeView`  like below and then control the property in your `ViewModel` or Code-behind.

```
<SwipeView IsEnabled="{Binding IsSwipeViewEnabled}">
    <SwipeView.RightItems>
        <SwipeItems >
            <SwipeItem />
        </SwipeItems>
    </SwipeView.RightItems>
    
</SwipeView>
```